# jquery event listener calling multiple times on dynamic list item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am trying to setup an event listener using jQuery,that will be called when a user clicks on a item in a dynamically created list.
This issue that I am facing is that initially when I click on the item nothing happens. While it works fine the second time but each time after that it appears to recursively call itself. I believe that this may be due to the focus.

Here is the Html

```
<div id="routes_list">
  <ul id="route_click">
    <li id="route_1" value="1"> One </li>
    <li id="route_2" value="2"> Two </li>
    <li id="route_3" value="3">Three</li>
    <li id="route_4" value="4"> Four </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '#route_click', function() {
  $('#route_click li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
})
```

You can try out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sedwardo123/bo0km94w/6/) with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by nesting event handlers.

When you first click an `li`, there's no event handler so it propagates up to the #route_click handler, which adds a click event handler.

Second click on the `li` runs the console.log handler, but then *also* propagates up to the wrapper which adds another handler, etc

As you're adding dynamic HTML (adding the HTML after the js runs) you can remove the "first" click and bind directly to the `li` (dynamically):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#route_click li', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="routes_list">
  <ul id="route_click">
    <li id="route_1" value="1"> One </li>
    <li id="route_2" value="2"> Two </li>
    <li id="route_3" value="3">Three</li>
    <li id="route_4" value="4"> Four </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your solution and very clear explanation as to why my code was acting like it was.